# Non-linear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

So I know how to solve linear partial differential equations but I am stuck on this new type of problem that is a nonlinear pde. The question is:

Determine the solution of $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=\rho^2$ which satisfies $\rho (x,0)=\sin x$.

Wolframalpha says the solution to this is $\frac{1}{c_1 - t}$ but then does that mean $c_1 = \frac{1}{\sin(x)}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple gives: $$\rho(x,t)=-\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)\cdot t-1},$$ so yes $c_1=\dfrac 1{\sin(x)}$.

Comment: but the partial derivative of that with respect to $t$ does not give $\rho^2$....or maybe I'm taking the partial derivative incorrectly..

Comment: Keep $x$ fixed.  Then $sin(x) = B$ where $B$ is a constant and $\rho(t)=-B/(Bt-1)$. Take the derivative wrt $t$ to get $d\rho/dt = B^2/(Bt-1)^2$. Multiply that with $1/\rho^2 = (Bt-1)^2/B^2$. You get 1.